# unity : How to delete unused assets?

Tags: unity

Hi i have some questions :

1. How to properly delete unused asset ?
2. I have an unused game object and i want to delete it together with its material/texture. I can select it and RMB select dependencies , but i can't delete them all because some of these selected textures is being used by other object. So i have to manually check them one by one. Is there any other faster method ?

Comment: That would break the other asset, wouldn't it?

Comment: If nothing references these assets, and they're not in a Resources folder or asset bundle / addressable / etc., then Unity should prune them out of your build automatically. Are you observing that this is not happening?

Comment: i have a main scene, then i imported some test game objects for playing with. I don't use these test objects in my main scene. These game object used textures which some of them also being used in main scene. I want to delete those test objects and their texture . The main scene didn't use these test objects so build process will ignore them (any unused) but i just want to tidy up some mess in my folders. There are many unused texture and objects there.

Comment: A search for "select unused assets" in Unity turns up lots of existing resources about this. What did you try so far, based on your research?

Comment: What i did so far : Try to select test (unused) object and RMB select dependencies. Check them make sure these are not used in main scene and delete them. This way i do it manually and really time consuming.